# Using a collating sequence specified in an LDML file for doing a line sort

Tags: sorting, perl, unicode, icu

I have an LDML file that specifies a collating sequence for a language not listed in /usr/share/locale.

I want to use the collating sequence from the LDML file to do a line sort in Linux.

My preferred tool is the bash sort command

I could also use the Perl [Unicode::ICU::Collator](https://metacpan.org/pod/Unicode::ICU::Collator) if I understood how to set it up with information from the LDML file.

Comment: I don't think GNU sort will do anything except locales. Unicode::ICU::Collator only supports `ucol_open`, not `ucol_openRules` (i.e. it can only access ICU's builtin collations) but if you [sent a feature request](https://github.com/tonycoz/Unicode-ICU/issues/new) TonyC might help you out :)

Comment: Do you need to sort large amounts of data, or just what will fit in memory?

Comment: @Shawn, the files can be loaded into memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A python (rather than perl) solution is available using the *icu* library documented at:

> https://github.com/silnrsi/collation

and

> https://scriptsource.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=entry_detail&uid=lcepuup9ga

Sample code is at:

> https://github.com/WesPeacock/ldml-sort